# Get last line from a mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql, row

Trying to get last line from a mysql table with php

```
$lastline="select COALESCE(ID, 0) from $sectionN order by ID desc limit 1"; 
$lastline=mysql_query($lastrow);
echo $lastline;
```

But it returs **"Resource id #9"**

Comment: What are you actually trying to get from the row?  Right now you are just echoing the row object.

Comment: I'm trying to get the last row ("number") so that I will continue editing my table from the last row

Comment: Didn't you asked the same question few hours back?

Comment: Try `var_dump($lastrow)` instead.  Should give you a bit more info about what's returned.

Comment: Not the same question

Comment: @Robert resource(9, mysql result)

Comment: Imagine I have 8 lines in my table, I want to edit from the last one

Comment: Sorry my mistake line not row

Comment: @AK47, Andrew Coder answered your question below, it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually fetch the result, then access the appropriate array index.
`$lastrow=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($lastrow))[0];`

---

+start using `mysqli`

`$lastrow=mysqli_fetch(mysqli_query($lastrow))[0];`

Comment: Of course, if you are trying to get the last inserted id, you can use `mysql_insert_id()` function.

Comment: Definitely agree with the mysqli usage.  Make sure to accept this answer if it fixed the issue @AK47.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake I'm trying to get last line not last row I edited my question

Comment: You still need to `fetch` whatever result you are looking for.  executing a query returns an object that still needs further processing to work with

Comment: Which is why you are getting "Resource id#9" instead of a row ID.

Comment: Yes understand, but how to modify this to get last line not last row : "select COALESCE(ID, 0) from $sectionN order by ID desc limit 1"

Comment: What's the difference between a line and a row?  Line of what?  Are you trying to get the latest ID to use later on for editing some "lines" that are related to it?

Comment: Imagine I have in my table 17 inserted lines (ids) I'm trying to get "17" so that I will insert from line 18

Comment: Then yes, my answer will give you #17, but that's not how you should manage unique ID's.  MySQL should have "PRIMARY AUTO_INDEX" set on the id column, then it does all the incrementing for you and you don't have to worry.

Comment: And row is the correct description.  17 rows, next auto increment would be 18.